# Let dim($V$) be infinite and $V$ be a normed vector space. Suppose $V=\cup_{n=1}^{\infty}W_n$, $W_n$ finite dim subspace of $V$. $V$ is not complete.

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra

This is a problem from Chapter 9 of N.L. Carother's Real Analysis text book. The chapter discusses the topic of Category.

The problem states:

> Let $V$ be an infinite-dimensional normed vector space, and suppose that $V=\cup_{n=1}^{\infty}W_{n}$ where each $W_{n}$ is a finite-dimensional subspace of $V$. Prove that $V$ is $not$ complete.

My first approach is to show that there is a Cauchy sequence $x_n^{(j)}\in V$ such that $lim_{j \rightarrow \infty}x_n^{(j)}\notin \cup_{n=1}^{\infty}W_{n}$. The dim($W_n$)  is finite and so each $W_n$ is closed in $V$ since every linear combination of vectors in $W_n$ belongs to $W_n$ . Let $x\in V$....

Here I am stuck, I want to show that there is a sequence in $W_n$ that converges to $x$ but $x\notin W_n$. But $x$ is an element of an infinitely dimensional each $W_n$ is finite dimensional so it seems that if I set entry whose index is greater than max$_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$( $dim(W_n)$ ) to some $\epsilon$ then $x_n^{(j)}$ will converge to $x$ but it won't be an element of any $W_n$. Am I on the right track?

Comment: By "the topic of Category", you presumably refer to Baire's theorem?

Comment: Yes that is correct. So this chapter talks about $F_\sigma$ sets and $G_\delta$ sets, actually before I got onto doing this problem using Cauchy sequences I was trying to show that $W_n$ was an $F_\sigma$

Comment: Then apply that theorem.

Comment: Yes But it seems to me that each $W_n$ is closed in $V$, but how can I show that each $W_n$ is nowhere dense? Also what is the relationship between dense-ness and completeness?

Comment: You assume that it is complete, and for complete spaces Baire's theorem applies, and show that this implies contradiction.

Comment: In a topological vector space (over $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$), the only linear subspace with nonempty interior is the whole space. Every proper linear subspace has empty interior.

Comment: Oh my gosh I think I see it.  If $V=\cup_{n=1}^{\infty}W_{n}$ and $V$ is complete, then some $W_n$ contains an open ball. But each $W_n$ is finite and $V$ is infinite, so there is a contradiction.

Comment: Yeah, looks okay to me. Basically if $W_n$ contains an open ball then anything in $V$ is a linear combination of basis vectors of $W_n$ since you can enlarge that ball as much as you want to whole space.